# jQuery slideUp() content when clicked for a second time

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would I slideUp() the content only when '.areaCodeList' is clicked a second time?

```
$(".areaCodeList").on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.churchList').slideDown();
    ($this.die());
    $('.churchList').slideUp();
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can check if the .churchList is visible (slided down):

```
$(".areaCodeList").on('click', function() {
    if( $(this).next('.churchList').is(':visible') === true){
        $(this).next('.churchList').slideUp();
    }else{
        $(this).next('.churchList').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks man! I just had to replace your code snippet `$('.churchList').slideDown();` with `$(this).next('.churchList').slideDown();` and now it works perfectly. and @epascarello, I have tried slideToggle() in the past but it never seemed to work. So how would you go about coding it?

Answer (score 0):

You may use some class to indicate it already clicked before running the code

```
$(".areaCodeList").on('click', function() {
  if (!$(this).is('.clicked')){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    return false;
  }
  $(this).next('.churchList').slideDown();
  $(this).die();
  $('.churchList').slideUp();
});
```

You also may consider using attributes (`$(el).attr('clicked')`) instead of class and check for it later in a similar way.

**Update:**
The question title is really confusing and it seems that only many of us (answering the question) don't got it from the start:

Initially I got it like this:

> Slide the element up if it clicked for the second time.
>   If it's the case than the sample I've provided is correct.

But it looks like the question is more like this:

> Slide the element down on every even click and slide it up on every odd click.

If this is the case that `slideToggle` is the solution (as explained in [epascarello's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9506757/155033))

Comment: @epascarello, already does what? Checking if it's clicked second time? I've only added check for second click leaving the rest of the code as is assuming it's correct since there is nothing in question saying it's the problem...

Comment: There is no need to do it. The method slideToggle() does the check. The solution is one line of code, no storing state, remove events, etc.

Comment: @epascarello, you're correct, I've just got the question wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

```
$(".areaCodeList").on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('.churchList').slideToggle();
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/rH7St)

Comment: @Jucicy Scripter Do you know what slideToggle is? Read the docs

Comment: Yep, I know and it have nothing to do with running on second click. The question title is a bit confusing. I've updated my answer and will take the vote back (if you'll edit the answer since it's already locked). Sorry for that